# Android - Change the TextStyle of ListView items

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I am developing one Android application having the list view of items. Those listview records are queried form the sqlite database. Here is the code of list view implementation:

```
       DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null);
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        private static final String fields[] = {"c"}; 
        int[] names = new int[] {R.id.name};
          client1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1 );

   String sql = "SELECT sno,a,b,c,d FROM (SELECT com.sno, com.a, com.b com.c,cd.d from table1 mem inner join table2 cd on mem.e=cd.e inner join table3 com on com.b = mem.b where mem.e =14445 AND a is NULL UNION SELECT com.sno, com.a, com.b,com.c,cd.d from table1 mem inner join table3 com on com.b = mem.b inner join table2 cd on mem.e=cd.e where mem.e =14445  AND a is NOT NULL) a group by a,b;";

  Cursor cdata = myDbHelper.getView(sql);

  SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list1, cdata, fields,names );
  client1.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

where list1.xml is:

```
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:orientation="horizontal" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
 android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
 android:padding="5px">  
 <TextView 
android:id="@+id/name" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textColor="#104082"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_weight="1" 
/>  
</LinearLayout>
```

**Here my problem is to differentiate the data records having 'a'=null and 'a'=notnull from the same list1.xml by changing the text style of the list view items....** Can I differentiate the text style in the sql query by giving any text style attributes in the query?

Please help me with the sample code/links...... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a CustomAdapter for the ListView . Since the View is created from the custom data object  which incudes all the cursor results.
You can check if a is null and have a different textstyle for the textview

Check [this](http://android-codelabs.appspot.com/resources/tutorials/contactsprovider/ex1.html) exercise for a custom adapter

Answer (score 2):

you have to define a custom list adapter and in it you have to define the getitemview method where you inflate (or programmatically change) the layout of the item, lets say list1_null.xml or list1_notnull.xml

If you need anything more than simply displaying the values (even something like changing color) you'd have to redefine a custom adapter.

ListAdapter example from android api: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html